# How do I improve my 'for' loop performance in terms of speed?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a for loop which it is taking almost 20 seconds for iterating 6907 rows. That loop does the job of making a list of unique region names in the given queryset.
I have placed timestamps at various places in the code to record the timings. The 'for' loop which is taking more time is between variables 't3' and 't4'.

timestamps

```
t = 12:27:22:169533
t2 = 12:27:22:173535
t3 = 12:27:22:793567
6907
t4 = 12:27:42:907362
t5 = 12:27:43:242596
t6 = 12:27:43:242596
```

6907 is the length of my queryset sales_data

views.py

```
class MSZoneProduct(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'sales/MSZoneProduct.html'
    form_class = MSZoneProductForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            form = self.form_class(request.GET)
            context = {'form': form}
            if form.is_valid():
                zone_code_ = form.cleaned_data['zone_name']
                product_code_ = form.cleaned_data['product_name']

                t = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S:%f')
                print("t = " + t)
                product = Product.objects.get(product_code=product_code_)
                t2 = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S:%f')
                print("t2 = " + t2)
                sales_data = Sales.objects.filter(zone_code=zone_code_, product_code=product).select_related()
                t3 = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S:%f')
                print("t3 = " + t3)
                print(len(sales_data))
                regions = []
                message = ""
                regions_dict = {}
                for x in sales_data:
                    if x.region_name not in regions:
                        regions.append(x.region_name)
                    else:
                        continue
                t4 = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S:%f')
                print("t4 = " + t4)
                for x in regions:
                    sum_ = 0
                    for y in sales_data:
                        if y.region_name == x:
                            sum_ = sum_ + y.quantity
                    regions_dict[x] = sum_
                t5 = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S:%f')
                print("t5 = " + t5)
                if len(regions) == 0:
                    message = "There is no data available for this product in this particular region."

                context = {'form': form, 'message': message, 'data': regions_dict}
                t6 = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S:%f')
                print("t6 = " + t6)
                return render(request, 'sales/MSZoneProduct.html', context)

            return render(request, 'sales/MSZoneProduct.html', context)
        else:
            return redirect('/sales/')
```

Comment: You can probably do some of this in the db. Show your models and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your view, you want to sum up the quantities per region. We can move all this logic into a database query. This will not only make it more efficient, but more elegant as well:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

sales_data = Sales.objects.filter(
    zone_code=zone_code_, product_code=product
).values('region_name').annotate(
    total_quantity=Sum('quantity')
).order_by('region_name')
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` that contains dictionaries with two elements: `'region_name'` that maps to the name of the region, and `total_quantity` that sums up the quantity for that region.

Next we can convert it to a dictionary `regions_dict` with:

```
regions_dict = { r['region_name']: r['total_quantity'] for r in sales_data }
```

Comment: This is expert thinking.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WillemVanOnsem . This solution is really fast.

Answer (score 2):

Use a set constructed with list comprehensions?

```
regions = set(x.region_name for x in sales_data)
```

The only problem is if you need the items in order. They could be sorted after the fact, your you could append them to a list depending on if they are successfully added to the set.

Edit: I agree that doing it in the database is the better approach (@Willem Van Onsem's answer), but this answer will be relevant for anyone who isn't using Django.

Answer (score 2):

The entire code from `sales_data = ...` to `t5 = ...` can be much more efficiently done with dict comprehension and `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
regions_dict = {k: sum(map(itemgetter('quantity'), g)) for k, g in groupby(Sales.objects.filter(zone_code=zone_code_, product_code=product).order_by('region_name').values('region_name', 'quantity'), itemgetter('region_name'))}
```

Comment: The style is very pythonic and compact. What is the complexity?

Comment: @Attersson: linear, since `groupby` works in linear time, and `sum(..)` sums in linear time the elements.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and groupBy does not add to the complexity, right?

Comment: @Attersson: well the groupby of itertools groups "bursts" together. It thus does *not* inspect if there are other items later in the "queue" that belong to the same group. The advantage is that it works *linear* and furthermore that it can work on infinite lists. As a result if you want to use real groups, you need to order first.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Very nice to know. In this case, this answer aces it.

Answer (score 1):

**Improving the for**
It is possible to directly store the sums at the first go in the dictionary with complexity O(N)

```
regions_dict_sums = {x.region_name:0 for x in sales_data}
for x in sales_data:
    regions_dict_sums[x.region_name]+=x.quantity
```

So the total regions where sales are greater than zero will be hashed in the dictionary as keys and their values are the total sales for that region, accessible at constant time.